# ¿Como pasar archivo de excel sin formato de celda con epplus en asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, epplus

Hola comunidad tengo un gran problema que no he podido resolver espero me puedan ayudar de antemano les agradezco mucho.

Mi situación es la siguiente tengo un archivo excel como el que se muestra en la imagen de abajo.

Quiero leer este archivo utilizando epplus y guardarlo como DataTable. He conseguido leer el archivo pero el problema es que me trae la información con los símbolos de $ y % lo cual requiero eliminarlos y solo obtener los números o las celdas vacías ya que posteriormente enviare esta DataTable a mi base de datos pero eso es otro tema.

¿Me preguntaba si podía leer el archivo de excel sin estos formatos de columna y solo obtener los numero o columnas vacías?

Aquí coloco mi código de como leo el archivo.

```
  public static DataTable ExcelToDataTable(string path)
    {
        using (var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                pck.Load(stream);
            }
            var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
            DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
            bool hasHeader = true; 
            foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, ws.Dimension.End.Column])
            {
                tbl.Columns.Add(hasHeader ? firstRowCell.Text : string.Format("Column {0}", firstRowCell.Start.Column));
            }
            var startRow = hasHeader ? 2 : 1;
            for (var rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
            {
                var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, ws.Dimension.End.Column];
                var row = tbl.NewRow();
                foreach (var cell in wsRow)
                {
                    row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
                }
                tbl.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            return tbl;

        }
    }
```

Aquí coloco la imagen del archivo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Intenta obteniendo el valor de la celda, no el texto.

```
row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Value;
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [answer] para poder mejorar tus respuestas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: Gracias por responder, te comento que de manera general, las respuestas que tienen solo código, sin una explicación de cuál es el problema o cómo el código lo resuelve se consideran de baja calidad. Sugiero que edites tu respuesta y añadas una explicación de por qué o como tu código resuelve el problema.

Comment: Hola @M. Ruiz muchas gracias no sabes cuanto estuve batallando con esto me esta funcionando muy bien muchas gracias.

Comment: Aunque la calidad de la respuesta no sea adecuada, no la hace incorrecta. No entiendo por qué es tan fácil emitir votos negativos cuando la respuesta se explica sola. De igual manera ya añadí una pequeña "sugerencia".